# "and" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> Go `and` play with the boys!
>
> Go play with the boys!

Is there any difference in meaning between these sentences? Is `and` optional here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It lends emphasis, but strictly speaking, yes, it's optional.